# Is it possible to create a Corda Schedulable State that continuously schedules activities without having to consume it each time?

Tags: corda

Based on the heartbeat sample project, my understanding is that if you want to schedule an activity on an interval (e.g. every 10 minutes) then you have to consume and produce a new state with the next scheduled activity each time. This seems unnecessary if nothing is changing except the next scheduled activity. Is there a way to have interval activities without consuming the state?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the SchedulableState is to have an event scheduled on the state at a particular time. For example- an auction going inactive when a deadline is reached, such that it stops receiving bids. SchedulableState is particularly useful in these kinds of use cases.

SchedulableState schedulable an event, the event triggers a flow. The flow mostly runs a transaction which will in mosyt cases (unless you are doing an issuance) consume a state.

However, if you want to schedule something which out a SchedulableState using a Service as below:

```
@CordaService
public class SchedulerService extends SingletonSerializeAsToken {

    private AppServiceHub serviceHub;

    public SchedulerService(AppServiceHub serviceHub) {
        this.serviceHub = serviceHub;
        schedule();
    }


    private void schedule(){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new Helper();

        timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000);
    }

    static class Helper extends TimerTask
    {
        public static int i = 0;
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Timer ran " + ++i);
        }
    }
}
```